# What do I need to fork to deploy Safe to a new chain?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to fork the Safe ecosystem to run on DogeChain https://chainlist.org/chain/2000 and I have no idea where to begin, can someone point me to the right direction please?

What I did:
Tried running https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts for chain 2000, got this error

> Error: ERROR processing
> /workspaces/safe-contracts/src/deploy/deploy_accessors.ts: Error:
> Safe factory not found for network 2000. You can request a new deployment at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory.
> For more information, see https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts#replay-protection-eip-155

So I did just that and created a deployment request: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/issues/110

I tried to compile and deploy my own singleton factory but it is giving me a different address from the other deployments so I suppose only the team have the  key  to deploy the factory for it to have the same address?

Anyways the end goal here is to deploy the safe ecosystem on Dogechain, can anyone point me to the right direction please

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only the team has the key to deploy contracts with predetermined contract addresses, because the key used to sign for contract deployment is controlled by the Safe team.

That's why you need to ask the support for your chain at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory, which is associated with the npm package of [`@gnosis.pm/safe-deployments`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gnosis.pm/safe-deployments).

Answer (score 0):

Found this after going through the whole docs https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/learn/infrastructure/service-architecture